# No SQL Server Agent in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

SQL Server Agent is missing from my SSMS.
I have attached the screen shot for your reference.
Please let me know if anybody knows the reason?

[image: Image of SSMS]

Comment: what edition and version of sql server are you running? the express edition does not have the agent available

Comment: please note, the post should be selfcontained without links to external sites

Comment: When I run this command select SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')    It says "SQL Azure"

Comment: That's correct, SQL Azure does not have SQL Agent. Are you migrating an on prem SQL Server or are you starting something new?

Comment: It is an old question I just edited. I started something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SSIS with Azure SQL Database, you need to use Azure Data Factory.

[image]

You use the SSIS catalog to store  your SSIS projects, and Azure Data Factory to schedule them.  You can also schedule them with [Azure SQL Database Elastic Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview#:%7E:text=Elastic%20job%20components%20%20%20%20Component%20,unit%20of%20work%20that%20is%20composed%20...%20).

Answer (score 1):

You're using Azure SQL DB. It does not support SQL Agent.

You'll need to look at using Windows Task Scheduler or a commercial product to provide scheduling services.

Comment: Thanks @billinkc. I need to schedule some jobs in SSIS. I am a new student of SSIS.